# Update old PhoneGap project with new version of PhoneGap projects. old PhoneGap project not created with the cordova CLI

Tags: android, cordova

I have an app I made a year ago. how can i upgrade it to new version.i read some phone gap documents , they suggest  run this one...

```
 bin/update <project_path>
```

i am trying this but i got error like 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

can any one briefly explain .give me one example.
complete path of the cli please.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `cd` into project directory -> `phonegap platform update android`? Off course via console/terminal

Comment: if it's older than 3.0.0, just create a new project and put your files inside the www folder. Install any plugin you use with the CLI. It will be easier than trying to update the project